# Geiger counter.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation, poisson-distribution

*The number of pulses that arrive to a Geiger counter follow a Poisson process of rate "three pulses per minute". Every pulses that arrive is registered with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. Let $(X(t),t\geq0)$ the process that describes, for every $t$, the number of pulses registered in $[0,t]$. Find, for a generic $t$:*

*1) $\mathbb{P}(X(t)=0)$.*

*2) $\mathbb{E}(X(t))$.*

*3) $\mathbb{P}(X(3)=6|X(2)=3)$.*

---

For 1) we have $$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X(t)=0) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{t}=k,X(t)=0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(N_t=k)\mathbb{P}(X(t)=0|N_{t}=k)\\
&=e^{-2t}\\
\end{align}$$

For 2) and 3) i'm stuck.

Could you please explain me how to set up the problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: For point 3), why we have
[image]

Comment: I assume 1 wanted you to give the whole PMF, after which 2 and 3 are pretty easy. Finding the PMF is a little tricky, though.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your answer. For 2) I think the solution is $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X(t)|N_{t}=k]]=\lambda t \mathbb{E}[X(t)]=\lambda t p$, with $\mathbb{E}[N_{t}]=\lambda t$ the expected value of the counting process, $\lambda =3$ the rate of distribution, $p=\frac{2}{3}$ and $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]$ that represents the probability. For 3) I've no idea.

Comment: You have a Poisson process (this is implied by part 1). Poisson processes have independent Poisson distributed increments. Thus $X(3)-X(2)$ is Poisson and independent of $X(2)$. What should be its parameter?

Comment: @Ian I asked my professor. Please Ian, could you please explain me why the equality in photo?

Comment: Because $X(3)-X(2)$ is Poisson, independent of $X(2)$, with mean given by the mean number of pulses in a time period of $3-2=1$.

Comment: @Ian I don't understand. I know that Poisson distribution enjoy the reproducibility: $X\sim Poi(\lambda_{1})\pm Y\sim Poi(\lambda_{2})=(X\pm Y)\sim Poi(\lambda_{1}\pm \lambda_{2})$, so I have to think that $X(3)\sim Poi(6)-X(2)\sim Poi(3)=X(3)-X(2)\sim Poi(6-3)$?

Comment: X(2) should be distributed as Poisson(4), but otherwise that is right. And the event in question occurs when X(3)-X(2)=3.